# Looking for the Docker way to get just the 1st Repository Tag in "docker inspect"

Tags: docker, shell

I'm trying to find the proper way to get just the 1st Repository Tag of a Docker Image in a Linux shell.

This can be achieved the ugly way by:

`docker inspect e77e5ce5d4e3 --format='{{.RepoTags}}' | tr -d "\[\]" | cut -f 1 -d ","`

It's says in https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/ that Docker uses [Go templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/). Looking at that page, I failed to find a way to get only a part of a range. Is there a way to do that? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `index` operation:

```
docker inspect e77e5ce5d4e3 --format='{{index .RepoTags 0}}'
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, so based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882553/iterate-over-a-variable-number-of-items-in-a-template-slice the solution is:

`docker inspect e77e5ce5d4e3 --format='{{range $index, $rt := .RepoTags}} {{if le $index 1}} {{$rt}} {{end}} {{end}}'`